# Chmod command over remote server using ssh NOT working

Tags: bash, ssh, scp, chmod

I have a bash script that copies over files from local to remote server using scp. Once all of the transfer is done, I run chmod command over the ssh to open up all of the permission. The problem is that it intermittently works and does NOT chmod 777 properly all the time. **Any way I can verify that chmod command executed definitely (maybe using return code or something)?** I do have my ssh keys setup so I do NOT need to enter password upon doing ssh or scp. Below is the snippet of my code

#copy over the files from local machine to remote server

```
scp file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt 10.111.222.333:/home/user1/fileDir/
```

#open up the permissions on the remote server

```
ssh -qX 10.111.222.333 chmod -R 777 /home/user1/fileDir
```

Comment: The exit code from the `ssh` command should reflect that of the `chmod` command -- that is, if `chmod` gets an error, `ssh` should return a nonzero code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:
`ssh server "chmod 755 file |echo $?"`

which would return 0

The `|echo $?` is checking the return code for the command ran.

Comment: If a file or dir doesn't exist and you run chmod over ssh with |echo $? you will get an exit status of 1 because there is no file or dir that exists, you'll get exit code 0 if things worked as expected